# Google contacts sync to Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, google-sync

Is there any way to sync google contacts to lotus notes?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: A Lotus Notes hater (user) me thinks ;-)

Comment: @fretje, if hating Notes was reason for down vote I would down vote too.:)

Comment: @sal: Sure, I'm not saying hating Notes was the reason, and I know I wouldn't down-vote for a reason like that, but without any other reason given, that's what I suppose here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Awesync http://www.awesync.com to sync contacts, cal and tasks

Answer (score 2):

It seems Google itself hasn't implemented sync for Lotus Notes (yet).
A Google query reveals that there are [workarounds for a calendar sync with Lotus Notes](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+calendar+sync+lotus+notes), but the *contacts nut* isn't cracked yet apparently.

Another thing I found: There is a [Lotus Notes Migration to Google Apps Toolkit](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2009/07/switching-to-google-apps-from-lotus.html).

I think we'll have to wait for an answer from Jon Skeet ;-)

Comment: I don't know of any way to sync with Lotus Notes. It's not something I've ever tried - thankfully :)

Answer (score 1):

Just found another sync product: DesktopMirror for Lotus Notes and Google (http://www.livepim.com/desktopmirror-lotus-notes-google/)

Answer (score 0):

I found [GooSync](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/GooCalSync) and [lngooglecalsync](http://lngooglecalsync.sourceforge.net/)

Neither will work for me but this might help some other poor soul.

Answer (score 0):

Import Export from Google Contacts frequently. I made a macro to do that once a week! hope that will work for hopeless Lotus Notes!